# Schauder Basis and its permutation

Tags: functional-analysis, permutations, schauder-basis

I have to answer the following question:

Let $\{x_n\}_{n\ge 1}$ be a Schauder Basis. Is $\{x_{\Pi(n)}\}_{n\ge 1}$, where $\Pi(n)$ bijection of $\mathbb N$ onto $\mathbb N$, also a Schauder Basis?

It seems to me that it is not true, but I can't show that formally.
Can you help me? I'm completely green in this topic.

Comment: It's not, necessarily. See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1560262/rearrangement-of-schauder-basis) for an example. You may also want to google "unconditional Schauder basis".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Schauder Basis $\{x_n\}_{n\ge 1}$ of the Banach space $X$ is called an  unconditional basis if for each $x \in X$ the series

$x= \sum_{n}\xi_n x_n$

is unconditionally convergent. The space  $C ( [ 0 , 1 ] )$  has a Schauder basis but no  unconditional Schauder basis .

Comment: thanks everybody! It starts to be clear but
I must think about it more